# Trying to understand .each() callback that sorts select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning js/jquery and am doing [this](http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0020_) exercise, sorting select options alphabetically. This is the solution they give:

```
<div id="target">
    <select>
        <option val="a">aaa</option>
        <option val="c">ccc</option>
        <option val="d">ddd</option>
        <option val="b">bbb</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    var options = {};

    $('#target option').each(function(i){
        var option = $(this);
        options[option.text()] = option;
    });

    var keys = Object.keys(options).sort();

    var select = $('#target select').empty();

    $.each(keys, function(i, key){
      select.append(options[key]);
    });
</script>
```

- Does the `i` parameter in the callback function of `$.each` relate to the `i` parameter in `$('#target option').each(function(i)`?
- If so, why does removing the parameter from `$('#target option').each(function(i)` not break anything?
- What is the `i` parameter doing in `$.each(keys, function(i, key)`? I only see key used in the function. Removing `i` from here does break the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No, they are separate, just like `name` here is separate:

  ```
  function sayHi(name) {
    alert("Hi, " + name);
  }
  function openWindow(url, name) {
    window.open(url, name);
  }
  ```

  They are separate functions, and each only defines parameters within its own scope.
- Removing `i` does not break anything because it is never used. JavaScript does not check how many arguments you passed. If you pass more than the function accepts, extras are ignored; if you pass less, then the missing ones will be given the value `undefined`.
- The first parameter in the callback of `$.each` will receive the index (or key) of the item (0, 1, 2, ...); the second, the value. (It is a bit confusing, because here values are called "keys".) If you remove the first parameter, the second parameter becomes the first, and your `keys` variable will now get the values 0, 1, 2.... that were funneled into `i` before.

Comment: Ahh okay. I clearly didn't understand what callbacks did. Only seen `forEach` so far. Just to clarify, the order is all that matters for parameters in callbacks, not what they're called?

Comment: Callbacks are normal functions - we just call them callbacks because they are called back from another function. Thus, everything you already know about how parameters work with function calls will also work with callbacks. So `function square(b) { return b * b; }` and `function square(x) { return x * x; }` are completely equivalent - same with callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

The i refers to the current iteration of the .each call. When a var is defined as a parameter of a function... it only exists in the scope if that function. The i is optional and only needs to be there if you want to know what iteration you are on.